# Using a list<Item> as DataSource in a Gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm a newbie with DataGridView and I'm trying to use a List as DataSource.

With my current code, my grid show me 3 lines with empty data inside. Can someone tell me what's wrong in this.

Here my code:

Item

```
    class Item
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string imagePath;
    public int type;
    public int hp;
    public int mp;
    public int str;
    public int dex;
    public int vit;
    public int agi;
    public int iInt;
    public int mnd;
    public int att;
    public int acc;
    public int def;
    public int eva;
    public int matt;
    public int macc;
    public string text;

    public Item()
    {

    }

    public Item(int Id, string Name, string ImagePath, int STR, int DEX, int VIT, int AGI, int INT, int MND,
                int ATT, int ACC, int DEF, int EVA, int MATT, int MACC, int HP, int MP, int Type, string Text)
    {
        id = Id;
        name = Name;
        imagePath = ImagePath;
        type = Type;
        str = STR;
        dex = DEX;
        vit = VIT;
        agi = AGI;
        iInt = INT;
        mnd = MND;
        att = ATT;
        acc = ACC;
        def = DEF;
        eva = EVA;
        matt = MATT;
        macc = MACC;
        text = Text;
    }
```

Here my form code :

```
    datagridItems.Rows.Clear();

        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

        Connection connection = new Connection();
        string requeteItems = "SELECT * FROM Items";

        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader myReader = connection.Read(requeteItems);

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            Item item = new Item();

            item.id = int.Parse(myReader["Id"].ToString());
            item.name = myReader["Name"].ToString();
            item.imagePath = myReader["Image"].ToString();
            item.hp = int.Parse(myReader["HP"].ToString());
            item.mp = int.Parse(myReader["MP"].ToString());
            item.str = int.Parse(myReader["STR"].ToString());
            item.dex = int.Parse(myReader["DEX"].ToString());
            item.vit = int.Parse(myReader["VIT"].ToString());
            item.agi = int.Parse(myReader["AGI"].ToString());
            item.iInt = int.Parse(myReader["INT"].ToString());
            item.mnd = int.Parse(myReader["MND"].ToString());
            item.att = int.Parse(myReader["ATT"].ToString());
            item.acc = int.Parse(myReader["ACC"].ToString());
            item.def = int.Parse(myReader["DEF"].ToString());
            item.eva = int.Parse(myReader["EVAS"].ToString());
            item.matt = int.Parse(myReader["MATT"].ToString());
            item.macc = int.Parse(myReader["MACC"].ToString());
            item.text = myReader["Text"].ToString();
            item.type = 0;
            items.Add(item);

        }

        connection.Close();

        bsItems.DataSource = items;
    }
```

Connection return datas without problem. I want to know why my lines got blank data.

Comment: Turn you `Item` class fields to properties by replacing `;` with `{ get; set; }`

Comment: try  bsItems.DataBind()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var bindingList = new BindingList<Item>(items);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
grid.DataSource = source;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Refer:**
[How to bind list to dataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228539/how-to-bind-list-to-datagridview)
[Binding List<T> to DataGridView in WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform)

Use a [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) and set the [DataPropertyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname.aspx)-Property of the column.

example:

```
var list = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person { Name = "Joe", },
    new Person { Name = "Misha", },
};
var bindingList = new BindingList<Person>(list);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
grid.DataSource = source;
```

**More binding related information..**

[Binding Controls to Data Created at Runtime](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2387)

Suppose you have an object that represents a data record and a list of these records should be displayed in a data-aware control. To allow this list to be bound to a control, you can do one of the following:

1. Use the **System.ComponentModel.BindingList<>** or **System.Collections.Generic.List<>** generic types to create a list. Unlike the List<> class, the **BindingList<>** class supports change notifications. When bound to this data source, a data-aware control will update itself when the underlying data changes.
2. Create a class encapsulating a list of records and implement the **IList**, **IListSource**, **ITypedList** or **IBindingList** interface for this class. The differences between these interfaces is described in the following section.

First of all convert you fields to property declaration and after that use the BindingList to enable full functionality with the control.

**References:**
[grid control - how to bind grid datasource to List ?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T232303)
[Bind DataGrid to Generic List<> will not allow Add, Edit items in Grid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q245536)
[Problem with data binding to DevExpress XtraGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486408/problem-with-data-binding-to-devexpress-xtragrid)