# How to sort in table, data from csv file to textbox?

Tags: c#, csv, textbox

When I read data from a csv file and write it to my textbox, I get the following result:

26/04/2021 16:08:50;4248,461;4676,146;6283,319;2136,178;8924,607;8419,497;0;1,349;0;0;1,915;0;1,819;2,386;236,5;229,4;237,9;8,17;6,12;7,75; 26/04/2021 16:08:51;4248,461;4676,146;6283,32;2136,178;8924,607;8419,498;0;1,374;0;0;1,912;0;1,825;2,363;236,6;229,3;237,9;8,16;6,23;7,77; 26/04/2021 16:08:52;4248,461;4676,146;6283,32;2136,178;8924,607;8419,498;0;1,344;0;0;1,91;0;1,812;2,379;236,6;229,4;238;8,15;6,1;7,72; 26/04/2021 16:08:53;4248,461;4676,146;6283,321;2136,178;8924,607;8419,499;0;1,374;0;0;1,898;0;1,808;2,332;236,5;229,3;237,9;8,1;6,23;7,7; 26/04/2021 16:08:54;4248,461;4676,146;6283,322;2136,178;8924,607;8419,5;0;1,385;0;0;1,899;0;1,813;2,327;236,6;229,4;238;8,1;6,27;7,72; 26/04/2021 16:08:55;4248,461;4676,146;6283,322;2136,178;8924,607;8419,5;0;1,397;0;0;1,9;0;1,774;2,277;236,8;229,3;238;8,1;6,32;7,56;

this is not clear and readable

How can I put these data in a nice sorted table in my TextBox?

My code to print the data in de textbox is:

'''private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\DellInspirion15\OneDrive\Documenten\SavedDataDigitaleTeller.csv", Encoding.UTF8);
TxtBxDataLogger.Text = text;
}'''

Comment: I already saw this exact question. What happend to it? Was it you ?

Comment: a text box is for text. A table is not a text, use a simple CsvHelper to create a list of custom object from that csv like https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-class-records/ . Then use it as data source of a grid. Grid are table. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093638/using-a-listitem-as-datasource-in-a-gridview

Comment: It was closed, but I work in shifts, so I did not see this. So I posted it again.

Comment: I'll have a look at the links, thx

Comment: Okay and is there a way to make rows with my data that I get from my csv file, to be put in a textbox? without making a table? For instance, if I load the data from my csv file, how can I program that the text can be 'printed' in my textbox without ';' and use 'tab + | + tab'?

Answer (score 0):

I put data into a datatable.  The data is 21 columns with first column a date.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;


namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        const int COLUMNS = 21;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            string[] rows = input.Split(new char[] { ';', '|'}).ToArray();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int rowCount = 0;
            int colCount = 0;
            Boolean headerRow = true;
            DataRow newRow = null;
            CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-BE");
            foreach (string row in rows)
            {
                string line = row.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    colCount = rowCount % COLUMNS;
                    if (headerRow)
                    {
                        switch (colCount)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                dt.Columns.Add(line, typeof(DateTime));
                                break;
                            default:
                                dt.Columns.Add(line, typeof(decimal));
                                break;
                        }
                        if (colCount == COLUMNS - 1)
                            headerRow = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (colCount == 0)
                        {
                            newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                            colCount = 0;
                            newRow[colCount] = DateTime.Parse(line, info);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newRow[colCount] = decimal.Parse(line, info);
                        }
                    }
                    rowCount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Lets give it a try ;-) Thx!

Comment: You can display in a DGV.   datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: Hi jdweng, I got an error (System.FormatException: 'The format of the input string is incorrect.')at the point: else
                    {
                        newRow[colCount++] = decimal.Parse(line, info);
                    }

Comment: What country?  Is comma in a number a decimal point or a separtion?  Do you know what the data looks like?  You can delete "info" in two places to use your country culture.  1)             CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-de");
2) From Parse(line, info); To Parse(line);

Comment: Belgium - I've changed it in the code. Comma isis used like  ','; in the csv file it's al ','. I'll give it a try by deleting 'info'.

Comment: Getting good results with Belgium so it should work without the culture : CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-BE"); and newRow[colCount++] = DateTime.Parse(line, info); and newRow[colCount++] = decimal.Parse(line, info);

Comment: Hi jdweng,
my sincere apologies, I have delivered you wrong information.
My mistake.

The code did not work correctly for me, because in the header of the csv file there are the quantities that I load from a telegram into the csv file. 

Completely my fault. Sorry.

So what it actually have and should have is:

datetime | consumption | injection | power | voltage | current ... underneath the data in decimals.  ... sigh ... And it's in wpf, so i've got a datagrid and no datagridview

Comment: I think you just have to skip first row.  I'll modify code.

Comment: See following for binding datagrid to datatable : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770438/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagrid